# Airflow MySQLToGCS Operator using up Memory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a Dag task that downloads a MySQL table to a GCS bucket.

However, the built in operator MySQLToGCSOperator that does this seems to store the data in memory until it has finished downloading the table.
Since some of our tables are 100 GB+ this leads the workers to use up all of the available memory while downloading large tables, leading our composer workers to fail at some point after they have consumed all the memory of the server.

Is there a way to download a MySQL table to GCS without consuming much RAM?

I have also tried changing the *approx_max_file_size_bytes* parameter and filetype (JSON/CSV) but that made no difference.

Using Airflow 2.0.2.

Composer image: composer-1.17.0-preview.6-airflow-2.0.2

Comment: It's not clear if you need a confirmation if it memory issue or if you need an alternative solution to MySQLToGCSOperator ?

Comment: I'd need you to specify the composer version you're using along Airflow 2.0.2. If your composer version does not longer support Airflow 2.0.2, it would be an explanation of why it may misbehave for you. Furthermore, I'd be great if you specify the issue you're targeting, because your question was quite ambiguous.

Comment: @MBHAPhoenix
I would like to know if this is normal and if so is there another solution?

Comment: @MariCruzR apologies for the ambiguity. Added more info to the question.

Comment: Is the MySQL DB hosted in [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql)? Or is it an external DB?

Comment: @Jofre Yes, everything is on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Since your target is to minimize impact on your RAM performance when downloading your MySQL table to GCS, I'd suggest to use a [serverless export to offload the effort](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export) from the primary instance. This can be achieved by using the gcloud export sql command with the --offload tag.

```
gcloud sql export sql INSTANCE_NAME gs://BUCKET_NAME/sqldumpfile.gz \
--database=DATABASE_NAME_1,[DATABASE_NAME_2…] \
--table=TABLE_1,[TABLE_2…] \
--offload
```

This method is supposed to help when exporting data from large databases, since it creates a secondary instance, and it's valid if you're using Cloud SQL.

Comment: I've edited my comment accordingly to the new version of your question. Please, review the solution content and tell me if this has helped your RAM performance.